# 楽しんでいるなと思います（なの意味）

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles, particle-な

> これは私の個人的な印象ですが、みんな本当に生活を楽しんでいる**な**と思います。

I was wondering what that な is standing for.

Answer (score 5):

In meaning,

> これは私{わたし}の個人的{こじんてき}な印象{いんしょう}ですが、みんな本当{ほんとう}に生活{せいかつ}を楽{たの}しんでいる**な**と思{おも}います。

＝

> これは私の個人的な印象ですが、「みんな本当に生活を楽しんでいる**な**。」と思います。

This 「な」 is a common sentence-ending particle used to ***casually conclude*** an impression/opinion.

> "This is just my personal impression, but I think everyone is really enjoying his life."

Like many other sentence-enders, 「な」 all by itself could not be translated easily.  You would only need to know it is used for a casual kind of conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

An extension to the "casually concluding" な explained by @l'électeur

### Short answer

な adds the nuance/emotional quality of "**I wonder**" to the sentence, be it positive, neutral, or negative. Granted, the way the "wonderment" is added is not a hard and fast rule, and varies by context. Note that in the English versions below, the "wonder" may seem contrived, but it's only to illustrate the point.

### Negative connotation examples

For negative expressions, the "I wonder" can be a "sarcastic softener", as can be the case in English:

- **うるさいな～**

> It's really noisy (and I wonder if you can turn down the noise for me,
>   thanks).

- **うるさいな～ v2**

> I wonder if you can stop talking, thanks.

### Positive/neutral connotation examples

- **いいな~**

> That's great! (I wonder if one day I might be able to have that too!)

- **やってもらえるかな**

> (I wonder) if you can do that for me.

- **みんな楽しんでいるなと思います**

> I was wondering to myself, "It looks like everyone's having a good
>   time"

- **わるいな**

> Thank you, (but with the following packed into it: "Sorry for making
>   you go through all the trouble of doing me that favor. I wonder if (hope that)
>   you won't hold it against me.")

- **すごいな**

> Wow, that was cooooool. (I wonder how he/she did that?)

Answer (score 1):

We might be able to understand it by comparing the one with it with the one without.

- 生活を楽しんでいると思う: I think they enjoy their lives
- 生活を楽しんでいるなと思う: I find the<s>y</s>m enjoying their lives

The latter implies that you have such impression by observing how actually they do something, while the former doesn't necessarily so. So, you can conclude that な stands for an impression formed through observation.