# Is there another meaning for 逃げるな？

Tags: meaning, particle-な

I know it means don't run away or sth similar.

I wonder does it has another meaning like--逃げよう(just run away)?

**Update**

For example, 「小鳥、逃げるな。」

Comment: Maybe this 「な」? -> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58785/9831

Comment: @Chocolate I have seen this, I just wanna know whether this phrase 逃げるな has such meaning? Or technically it's possible but people don't actually use it?

Comment: what triggered this question? if you explain the context or other circumstances leading to it, we may be able to help better.

Comment: `people don't actually use it?` -- 「私なら逃げるな(ぁ)。」「あの人はいつもそうやって逃げるな(～)。」「うまく逃げるな(あ)。」とか、別におかしくないと思います。

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky My fault, should have posted the context. Have updated my question.

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks a lot for your examples and patience, see my update.

Comment: that's not much context. where is it from? what's happening before/after this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「小鳥、逃げるな。」

It can mean either "Don't run away/escape" (negative imperative) or "(I think) ~~ will run away/escape". It depends on the context. For example...

「あっ、待て！小鳥、逃げる**な**！」 -- would be interpreted as "Don't go".

「あっ、鳥かごが壊れてる。これじゃあ、小鳥、逃げる**な**。」 -- would be interpreted as "Birds will/may escape".

Comment: "Don't escape!" is pronounced [逃げるな]{LHLL} (or [逃げるな]{LHLH}). "~~will escape" is pronounced [逃げるな]{LHLH}.

Comment: cf. 「笑うな」だと、"Don't laugh" は「[わらうな]{LHHL}」で、"~ (will) laugh" は「[わらうな]{LHHH}」ですね・・

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Pretty exhaustive answer!