# What's the use of ね in the following two sentences?

Tags: particles

> 私はそろそろ寝るね。

I understand ね as *is it?* or *isn't it* (I think it has other uses)?

But in the example above:

> I will go to bed early.

I can't see any possible use for ね. Maybe it could act as "okay?" But I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider this brief citation from the Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar:

> ね
>
> A sentence final particle that indicates the speaker's request for
>   confirmation or agreement from the hearer about some shared knowledge.

Second, consider that そろそろ here might be better translated as "soon".

Of course there's no perfect direct translation of ね, but your choice of "okay?" seems reasonable in this case.

Putting it together:

> I'm going to bed soon, okay?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've seen ね in even stranger places like あなたは、きっと日本の抹茶ティーは嫌いだね. In this sentence, I have no idea about the purpose of ね. Maybe it could be "right?" But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, it means "right?" in that case. This falls under "request for confirmation" as described by DoJG.

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot It depends on the context, and the condition with which you can translate it to "right" is limited to a situation where both the speaker and the listener experience something that reveals the listener's taste in the moment. Otherwise, it's a basic function of な/ね explained here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58779/%e6%a5%bd%e3%81%97%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a8%e6%80%9d%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ae%e6%84%8f%e5%91%b3